# Search box needs to be able to search individual words from search box

Tags: android, search, app-inventor

I am using MIT **App Inventor 2** and I am trying to make my search box more useful.

Right now a have a bunch of lists and it only works if the words in the "search" textbox match the word in the list exactly. I want it to be more dynamic. For example
If someone puts `oj container` in the search box I want it to search the lists for `oj container` and if that does not come up with anything then search the lists for both `oj` and `container` separately. And if it finds one of these words in the list to follow on to the next action, which is to open up the appropriate page.

So far my code looks like this:

[image]

Tell me if this code make sense. Thanks.

[Here are some more code screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f08bX.jpg)

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of your blocks instead? You can upload it to a service like http://imgur.com, then **edit your question** and add a link to the screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Great Idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not make sense. The `split at spaces` block returns a list and using the `is in list?` block you can't search for a list of things, only for a "thing" (a single word in your case). Therefore you will have to search for each single word in your list using a `for each item in list` loop.

Also there is some redundancy in your blocks. If searching for `oj container` is successful, the search for `oj` also is successful, which means, you can remove the blocks to search for the complete sentence...

See my solution for the first part of your screenshot.

[image]